# What is the correct OracleDBConnection with OracleSQLplus?

Tags: oracle, asp.net-core, database-connection, connection-string, sqlplus

I am using  ASP.NET Core MVC and i try to connect to a hosted database...

[image: oracle sql plus screenshot]

but i don't know what is the correct connection string
I tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
 "OracleDBConnection": "Data Source = (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=xx.xx.xx/ConnectionIndicator)));User ID=name;Password=password;"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a90842/ch2.htm):

> Connection Identifier:

> Leave this field blank to use the default Oracle database if one exists, otherwise enter an Oracle Net alias to specify a remote database you want to connect to. If you use an Oracle Net alias, it must be defined on the machine running the iSQL*Plus Server, which may not be the same machine from which you run your web browser.

> You can also use the full connection identifier, for example:

> (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=www.oracle.com)
> (PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=((SERVICE_NAME=orashop.us.acme.com))

> iSQL*Plus can be configured to restrict connections to specific databases. If restricted database access has been enabled, a dropdown list of available databases is displayed in place of the Connection Identifier text field. This allows greater security for iSQL*Plus Servers in hosted environments.

---

iSQL*Plus? Someone still uses it? Boy, that's *ancient*.

Comment: https://i.postimg.cc/QdxwLnzM/image.png + https://i.postimg.cc/VLFpVcDT/image.png

Comment: The 2nd screenshot says "no listener". Check with DBA why is that so.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using oracle database with .NET core then need to install few nuget packages.

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore
Oracle.ManagedADataAccess.Core
```

After this need to write some code in the configureServices method of startup class.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<OracleDbContext>(options=>options.UseOracle(Configuration.GetConnectionString("OracleConnection")));            
}
```

OracleDbContext class is inherting from the DbContext class and OracleConection connection string is set up in the appSettings.json file.

**OracleDbContext.cs**

```
public class OracleDbContext : DbContext
{
   public OracleDbContext(DbContextOptions options):base(options){}
}
```

**appSettings.json**

```
{
"ConnectionStrings":{
   "OracleConnection":"Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS= 
 (PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST={url of your database})(PORT={port})))(CONNECT_DATA= 
 {name of your database for ex: SID})));User Id={user id};password= 
 {password}:"
 }
}
```

Values in bracket {} needs to be replaced. This connection string is used when the database is on the server, not locally.